# How to query intent filter's data from in Androidmanisfest.xml file from currently running application?

Tags: android-manifest

Using Android API level 10, **how to query intent filter's data (defined in AndroidManifest.xml file) in currently running application (my own app) ?**

PackageManager seems not to be capable of handling this.

Eg:

My app contains:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DETECTED">
</action><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
</category>
    <data android:scheme="nfc"android:host="secure"android:port="1"/>
</intent-filter>
```

From this AndroidManifest.xml file, I would like to extract value 1 from android:port="1".

Comment: Have you found the answer to your problem yet? I'm trying something similar, to enumerate all the BroadcastReceivers listed in the AndroidManifest.xml of our app and get the value of android:priority in the inten-filter of each BroadcastReceiver or get the sorting as defined in the manifest-xml if the priority is not given.

Comment: Not yet. I keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android API don't provide any API to achieve this. However, as a workaround I copied the AndroidManifest.xml file and parsed the content target with an XML parser.